# mysql trigger to update another table row with same columns

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables with the same columns. I have a trigger that adds data from `table_1` to `table_2` AFTER INSERT in `table_1`. How can I create a trigger which will update the updated row from `table_1` to `table_2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the same way you made your `AFTER INSERT` trigger, just specify `AFTER UPDATE` instead:

```sql
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_uau_table_1_table_2 AFTER UPDATE ON table_1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `table_2`
    SET    `a`  = NEW.a ,
           `b`  = NEW.b ,
    WHERE  `id` = OLD.id;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

*(I did not test though.)*

MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Thanks i just want to know the syntax of update tirgger.